# There has to be a better way

Tags: python, modulo

Is there a more idiomatic way to accomplish the following in Python3?

```
if i%1 == 0 and i%2 == 0 and i%3 == 0 and i%4 == 0 and i%5 == 0 and i%6 == 0 and i%7 == 0 and i%8 == 0 and i%9 == 0 and i%10 == 0 and i%11 == 0 and i%12 == 0 and i%13 == 0 and i%14 == 0 and i%15 == 0 and i%16 == 0 and i%17 == 0 and i%18 == 0 and i%19 == 0 and i%20 == 0:
```

I'm trying to find the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20. I'm not looking for a new solution. I'm looking for a neater way to express what I am doing above.

Comment: Try using a `for` loop. Also, please format your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes use [*all*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) with [*range*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range):

```
if all(i % j == 0 for j in range(1, 21)): # python2 -> xrange(2, 21) 
   # do whatever
```

If all `i % j == 0`, it will return *True* otherwise it will *short circuit* and return *False* if there is any remainder for `i % j`. Also, checking `if i % 1` is redundant so you can start at 2.

Or conversly, check if there is *not* [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) `i % j` with a remainder.

```
if not any(i % j for j in range(2, 21)):
```

Or if you prefer *functional*:

```
if not any(map(i.__mod__, range(2, 21)))
```

Comment: Or on Py2, for mild perf benefits, `xrange`. Not a big deal either way though, given the range is small.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, true, added a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `all` function combined with a list comprehension - or better yet - a generator expression:

```
if all(i%(1 + j) == 0 for j in range(20)):
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop in a while loop.

```
num = 1;
while(True): #keeps going until it finds the number
    b = True #remains true as long as it is divisible by div
    for div in range(1,21):
        if not (num % div == 0):
            b = False #number was not divisible, therefore b is now false
            num += 1
            break
    if(b): #b means num was divisible by all numbers.
        break
print(num)
```